# How to set an app's visibility in android apps explorer

Tags: android

Here's a simple **example** of what I'm going to do: 
- You have a main application called "Words". After installing this you search the modules in Play Store and install two, called "Words: A" and "Words: B". And then when you open "Words" it will load the installed modules. But each time you add a module the phone handle it like other application and an icon appears in the applications explorer. If you have 26 modules installed it will be messy. Can I make this modules invisible in the explorer?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "modules"?

I'm not sure i fully understand, however, i think what you are trying to do can be accomplished using Intent Filters:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

the reason that your other modules are popping up (if i understand correctly) is because they can be opened by the applications explorer since they have a main activity whose main intent filter is

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

which puts it in the LAUNCHER. take out the intent filters for LAUNCHER and your app should no longer appear in the app explorer

if your module isn't an app, don't put it on the Google Play store. have it be downloaded from a hosted server somewhere via your app. if it's meant to be a library, make it a library instead. if it's a framework, make it that instead, and import it into your code.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I can manage that intents to hide the app. Don't know how I didn't remember it. Thanks!

Comment: i've done worse XD by the way, if it's not too much to ask, would you be willing to upvote the answers that you accept? it gives more points to the answerer and encourages more participation :D if that's too much of a shameless request, i totally understand :)

Comment: Yes, it encourages. We are all programmers and we have our work, and it's not being here helping the others :)